# I want shipment Id so my code not excute every time

Tags: magento2

```
public function execute(Observer $observer)
  {
    $items = $observer->getEvent()->getShipment()->getAllItems();
    if ($items) {
      foreach ($items as $item) {
        $productId = $item->getProductId();
        $qty = $this->stockState->getStockQty($productId);
        $itemQty = $item->getQty();
        if ($qty < $itemQty) {
          $sourceItem = $this->sourceItemFactory->create();
          $sourceItem->setSourceCode('default');
          $sourceItem->setSku($item->getSku());
          $sourceItem->setQuantity($itemQty);
          $sourceItem->setStatus(1);
          $this->sourceItemsSaveInterface->execute([$sourceItem]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Your question is not much clear. Can you please explain a bit more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code it seems you always want to allow customers to purchase products and never want to go your product our of stock.

If so then Magento by default provides the option to allow your customers to purchase the product with worrying about product stock going to out of stock.

[image]

In Stores -> Configuration -> Catalog ->Inventory tab.

**Option1 :- Manage Stock**

Set Manage stock to NO in Product stock options and then Magento will consider that product has an unlimited stock level.

**Option2 :- Backorder**

This option provides many other options as well, for complete reference you can use the official page [Backorder](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-admin/inventory/configuration/backorders.html)

Comment: no actually when we create shipment and product qty less than order ship qty then we get error on shippment so shipment not created

Comment: try $observer->getEvent()->getShipment()->getId() to get the shipment it.

Comment: its given 1 in log  when i create shipment its correct?

Comment: hopefully if it is your first shipment then yes.

Comment: If this answer works as your expected, please mark it as accepted. That indicates your issue is solved and makes it easier for others with the same issue to find a verified answer. And that would be great if you click the upvote button for the answer in case you feel it is useful.